# Dropwizard-Hystrix-Hibernate Sql exceptions

Tags: hibernate, dropwizard, hystrix

I have an api where it takes long time to process if the data fetched from sql is huge. But we have a constraint to limit the time of the api and hence we introduced hystrix in our code. We placed the crucial part of code inside hystrix command. This code fetches the data from sql in batches of 10, processes it and then adds it to the list. By the end of timeout I return whatever I have accumulated in the list. My problem is happening when the hystrix times out, the sql connection gets interrupted and then I am not able to access the result set. I get errors like ***"You cannot operate on a closed result set or you cannot operate on a closed statement"***

I am using Open session in view pattern in spring. When the hystrix command finishes before the timeout period, there are no issues but when the hystrix commands gets interrupted, the SQL issues come up. Any advice on how to solve this?

Comment: Ok. Still it does not answer anything to my problem.

Comment: what do you want to do exactly when hystrix times out ? Do you want to release your resources like connections etc ?

Comment: Yes I wanted to do that. But anyways I have used the DTOs approach to avoid lazy loading at the end.

Comment: what do you mean by DTOs ?